# Given $\mathrm{Gal}(E/ F)$ find $E$ and $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, galois-theory

There's a theorem that states that

> for any finite group $G$ there exist a field $F$ with finite separable normal extension $E \supset F$ such that $G\cong \mathrm{Gal}(E/ F)$.

Is there an algorithm or a methods that allows to find such $E$ and $F$ with given $G$? I'm mostly interested in cases $G=V_4,D_4,C_4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, $D_4$ is the dihedral group with $8$ elements. $C_2\times C_2$ is $V_4$ (or $D_2$)

Comment: One proof of the theorem you cite views the given group $G$ as a subgroup of some suitable symmetric group $S_n$, sets $E$ equal to $k(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ the field of rational functions in $n$ indeterminates over a ground field $k$, and sets $F$ equal to the subfield of $E$ fixed by the permutation action of $G$.  Are you trying to fine **all** extensions $E/F$ for which $G$ is the Galois group?

Comment: @DCarter, ok, I see, thank you! Not **all**, just **any** :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$There is a result, called [Artin' s Lemma](http://people.virginia.edu/~mve2x/7752_Spring2010/lecture20.pdf)  that tells you the following.

> Let $E$ be a field, and $G$ be a finite group of automorphisms of $E$. Let $F$ be the set of fixed points of $G$, that is,
>   $$
> F = \Set{ a \in E : a g = a \text{, for all $g \in G$}}.
> $$
>   Then $E/F$ is a Galois extension, with Galois group $G$.

Now let $G$ be a finite group. Without loss of generality, you may assume that $G \le S_{n}$ for some $n$. Let
$$
E = \Q(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})
$$
be the function field in $n$ variables. Then $G$ acts on $E$ as a group of automorphisms, by permuting the $x_{i}$ and we are done.

---

Your special cases can be dealt with in an easier way.

For $V_{4}$, take $\Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})/\Q$.

For $D_{4}$, take $\Q(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)/\Q$

For $C_{4}$, take $F(\sqrt[4]{2})/F$, where $F = \Q(i)$, or $\Q(\omega)/\Q$, where $\omega$ is a primitive fifth root of unity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please comment on how you get $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)/\mathbb{Q}$ for $D_4$?

Comment: The Galois group has order $8$, which is the degree of the extension, and can be regarded as a group of permutations on $4$ elements, the roots of $x^{4} - 2$. Now the $2$-Sylow subgroup of $S_{4}$ has order $8$, and it is dihedral. Alternatively, note that an element of the Galois group is determined by its action on $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $i$. There is an element that fixes $i$ and sends $\sqrt[4]{2}$ to $i \sqrt[4]{2}$. This will have order $4$. Then there's complex conjugation, which is an element of order $2$ which inverts the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

We can follow the usual construction for such a Galois extension $E/F$ from the proof of the Theorem: if $|G|=n$, then take $E=\mathbb{C}(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$, and $k=\mathbb{C}(s_1,\ldots ,s_n)$, the subfield generated by the symmetric polynomials. Then $E/F$ is Galois, and by construction has $Gal(K/k)=S_n$. We have a canonical embedding of $G$ into $S_n$ by the group action of $G$ on itself by left multiplication. 
Let $H ⊂ S_n$ be the image of that embedding. By Galois correspondence, there exists an intermediate field $F$ so that $Gal(E/F) = H\cong G$.